# Set static IP on Centos7

Tags: ansible, centos7

I have a CentOS7 box that I need to change from DHCP to Static IP.  I am using the ansible code below and I keep getting message.  I have installed the required packages for this to work, so I dont think that is the issue.

`"FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Error: Failed to modify connection 'System ens192': No such method 'Update2'\n", "name": "System ens192", "rc": 1}"`

I know the ifname is "ens192"  not sure about the conn_name. I did a "nmcli connection show" and a "nmcli device show" but none of them seem to work.

I have tried for the conn_name "ens192, System ens192, my-en192" and I get the same error message just with the different conn_names.

I would ultimately like to have these values set by the gathering facts procedure, but not sure how to do this?

```
  - name: Add an Ethernet connection with static IP configuration
    nmcli:
    conn_name: ens192
    ifname: ens192
    type: ethernet
    ip4: 192.0.2.100/24
    gw4: 192.0.2.1
    state: present
```

Comment: It may just be your cut-and-paste, but the options need to be indented.

Comment: can you try to restart NetworkManager then retry?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "nmcli connection show" and a "nmcli device show" but none of them seem to work

It should work.

Did you install dependancies for this module?
If not you can install them with ansible this way:

```
  - name: install needed network manager libs
    package:
      name:
        - NetworkManager-glib
        - nm-connection-editor
        - libsemanage-python
        - policycoreutils-python
      state: present
```

Or just yum install them.

Comment: yes, all the dependencies are installed.  When I run the nmcli I do get an output, and I have tried to put the name on my ansible script, but I keep getting the same error message.

Comment: sorry I understood that the command itself did not work! can you provide  the output of the command?

Answer (score 0):

When I run the nmcli commands, this is the output I get.  I have tried to use on the conn_name: ens192 and System ens192 and both give me the same error message.

```
nmcli device show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         ens192
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:50:56:87:FB:F1
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     System ens192
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.21.10.100/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.21.10.254
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DNS[2]:                             4.2.2.2
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
[root@kamailio01 ~]# nmcli connection show
NAME           UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
System ens192  2df1f002-52f2-4d9c-b7dd-7af061eceb34  ethernet  ens192
```

Comment: You should move this into the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my work, I've just had a Jinja2 template and used the `template` module to overwrite the `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-whatever` file.